# How do I handle the table border like this?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I wish to achieve a table border like this (notice the thick border under the 3<sup>rd</sup> row):

[image: ![enter image description here]

So, I coded as the one given below,

```css
body {
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 25%);
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}

table {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
caption {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

th {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, .5);
    width: 10%;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<table>
    <caption>TableCaption</caption>

    <tr>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th rowspan="2">SpannedRow1</th>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th rowspan="2">SpannedRow1</th>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And it ends up like this (notice that the border under third row isn't thick):

[image]

Now I would like to know in which way if handle the table border so that I can have the expected result.

Comment: can you add a class to every `td` that needs the border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using nth child for the table row as below:

```
tr:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

Here I have updated your code snippet:

```css
body {
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 25%);
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}

table {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
caption {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}

th {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, .5);
    width: 10%;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 15%;
}

tr:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<table>
    <caption>TableCaption</caption>

    <tr>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
     <th>TableHeader</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th rowspan="2">SpannedRow1</th>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th rowspan="2">SpannedRow1</th>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
     <td>TableData</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if the length of every span is irregular?

Comment: In that case you need to give style for each span separately. ( Can use class for common style). Make sense ?

Answer (score 1):

Hoping can help you

`tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}`